# C# File Name Formatted Like a Web Address

Tags: c#, visual-studio, path, filenames

I've got a file name that I am **unable** to change.
This is an example of what the file name looks like "www.Test.somee.com"

If I try and path to this file name in Visual Studio it will error because of all the full stops.

What's a way of making C# recognize this is a file name and not code?

This is the line I'm using it for.

```
public partial class www.Test.somee.com_Website_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
```

I recieve all these errors for that one line.

```
Error   2   Invalid token '.' in class, struct, or interface member declaration     
Error   3   Invalid token ':' in class, struct, or interface member declaration     
Error   5   The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a 
definition for 'www'
```

Comment: The file name is a valid filename so precisely are you trying to use the file in VS and what's the error?

Comment: You still haven't provied any example of usage

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Voting to close.

Comment: I have edited it and given an example of the code and the errors.

Comment: Did you mean to put this in `namespace www.Test.somee` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a page that has such name, because it's invalid. (that's what those errors mean)

If you want such ugly names, you'd have to substitute `.` for a different character, for instance `_` or `-`.

Please see general guidelines for naming your classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Looks like I'll just have to try a new method then. Thanks.